# How to fetch UNREAD(UNSEEN) emails with curl in an IMAP server in linux?

Tags: linux, email, curl

I search and researched in the web BUT I only found tutorials about how to fetch unread emails for gmail using curl in Linux!!!and I found how to fetch emails with specific UID, for example UID=1 (oldest email) but I need help to set curl to fetch only unread messages (RECENT messages or UNSEEN messages) in the INBOX folder of an IMAP server (NOT gmail), how to do that?? , I appreciate any help, thanks, vladimir